# NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification firing for ALL windows

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I have an app with two windows - a main window, and a preferences window which can be opened from the menubar. I am trying to implement a notification that the preferences window becomes the main window so that I can update it when it is opened, however my notificaton is firing whenever any window opens, even a different window.

inside my PrefsWindowViewController.m awakeFromNib I have:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didBecomeMain:)
                                             name:NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And in my PrefsWindowViewController.m dealloc, I have:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name: NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification object:nil];
```

Can anybody explain why this might get called when a different window besides my PrefsWindow becomes the main window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're passing `nil` for the `object:` parameter. Pass your preferences window instead, or check `[notification object] == yourPrefsWindow` in your callback.

Comment: Thanks so much. It seems so obvious now but I just set the object to [self window] instead of nil and it worked. I hope this question/answer helps somebody else out there...